# plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.core.audiohandler

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

we have a zip file that uploaded and compiled just fine in December 12, 2013.  Now the exact same zip file gives this new error (`"plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.core.audiohandler`") and refuses to compile.

We are using `phonegap 3.0`, and are using the `audio library`.  I would rather not take out the calls to the library as they are part of our feature set.

Is there a replacement library that we should be using, or a different set of methods? We are using the

```
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(onAudioSuccess, onAudioFailure, {}); call.
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

PS - org.apache.cordova.audiohandler is not supported either apparently

Answer (score 0):

Starting with phonegap 3.0, you have to install plugins for the core apis of phonegap you use.

So you have to add the following line to your config.xml :

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
```

Comment: Thanks QuickFix for the reply, but I think this is a phone-gap build issue, as we went to phoneGap 3.0 about 4 months ago and it built fine on the phonegapbuild site until just now.  Indeed this fix you suggest does let the app compile, but now I have to find all the other plugins that I want (GPS, network, etc)

Comment: you'll find all core plugins referenced in the phonegap documentation and there : https://build.phonegap.com/plugins